# Can the em dash replace both the semicolon and comma in these?

Tags: punctuation

Can the [em dash](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dash#Em_dash) replace the comma and semicolon in these sentences? For example, instead of "The original sign did not have terminal punctuation; thus, the full stop goes outside the quotes to end the sentence", can we do this? (See below.)

- The original sign did not have terminal punctuation – *thus* the full stop goes outside the quotes to end the sentence.
- The original sign did not have terminal punctuation – *hence* the full stop goes outside the quotes to end the sentence.
- The original sign did not have terminal punctuation – *therefore* the full stop goes outside the quotes to end the sentence.
- The original sign did not have terminal punctuation – *as a result* the full stop goes outside the quotes to end the sentence.
- The original sign did not have terminal punctuation – *consequently* the full stop goes outside the quotes to end the sentence.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. But I don't understand why you removed the commas in the examples with dashes.

Dashes can replace ***semicolons***, **colons**, and **ellipses**, albeit are considered *informal*.

**Note**: they may also be used as **parenthesis**:--

My homework--all Math-, English-, and Science-related--is due tomorrow. **em-dashes* have been used.

My homework (all Math-, English-, and Science-related) is due tomorrow.

My homework, all Math-, English-, and Science-related, is due tomorrow.

All are acceptable methods.